# How to return a custom type <Hero> from View (GUI) to controller?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, blockingqueue, eventqueue

I'm making an MVC game called Swingy for a 42 project, it requires me to have a console and a GUI view implemented in the MVC pattern. I figured that I would have an instance of my view (either GUI or console within the controller). So I made an interface called Viewable that both views would implement. The issue is that my controller calls this.view.newHero() which should return a new Hero() object, but I can't figure out how to get the return value from the GUI.

I've tried using a ArrayBlockingQueue but the issue seems to stem from the return value in my interface.

Controller

```java
public GameController() {
    this.view = new GUI(); // Just for testing, will either be new Console or new GUI
    this.hero = this.view.newHero(); // The problematic function
    this.makeNewBoard();
    this.gameBoard.printBoard();
}
```

Interface

```java
public interface Viewable {
  public Hero newHero();
}
```

Console View newHero method (shortened)

```java
public Hero newHero() {
  name = getInput();
  heroClass = getInput();
  return new Hero(name, heroClass);
}
```

GUI

```java
public Hero newHero() {
  //Here I've tried making a blockingQueue and waiting for input but the issue is that my function must return a Hero type. If I return null then it causes an issue in the controller.
}
```

In the GUI view the user clicks a button to start a new game, then a JOptionPane input Dialog should open and ask for the hero name. It should then return a new Hero with this name.

Comment: *it causes an issue in the controller* nullcheck then .

Comment: I don't see enough information to make this answerable. Usually your controller will request information from the view when the program state makes a request for the information, and so the information should already be ready. The model should be aware when the view's state changes (usually via a observer pattern), when the view's state has changed and data is available.

Comment: In fact, your question and code are completely devoid of information about the model, and this should be the first and main thing that you work on, *before* considering view and controller elements.

Comment: ... and what triggers the controller to make this request? Information that we don't have, again making the question vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that now. Is there a proper way to get Swing to wait for the user to complete the cycle and then return the value?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels for simplicity you can assume the model just contains a Hero's name. So the complete flow is that a main frame is opened, the user can click "new game" or "load game". Focusing on "new game", an input dialog is opened prompting for the hero's name. So I started the controller and the Console View first, and this is fully functional, but modifying it to allow for user input via the GUI is troubling, because the controller does not wait. I'm not sure if this is usually done but the full code can be found here https://github.com/TlStephen2011/Swingy.

Comment: `"Thanks, I'll do that now. Is there a proper way to get Swing to wait for the user to complete the cycle and then return the value?"` -- you generally don't. You're using an event-driven GUI library, and the way this is solved is to wait for events signaling that the data should be extracted. Otherwise, you're fighting against the library.

Comment: What is usually done is to distill your code to a [mre], a very small *new* program that distills the concepts from your own code, that compiles and runs for us and that shows us your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the info, I'll edit my question including things that I have learnt here. Thanks again.

Comment: It is not clear to me what stops you from having  `newHero()` in gui similar to the one in console implementation ?  Get the input from the user using a `JDialog` as you wrote.